# Aligning facetted plots and legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, cowplot

I'm trying to plot facets with each facet having its own legend. However, I am having some trouble to get it all aligned properly.

```
dat <- structure(list(group1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), group2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), x = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "2"), y = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "3")), .Names = c("group1", 
"group2", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

dat <- split(dat, f = dat$group1)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(dat$A) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=group2)) +
  facet_wrap(~group1) +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=2)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(a = "green", b = "red", c = "blue"), 
                      labels=c(a = "green", b = "red", c = "blue"))

p2 <- p1 %+% dat$B
```

Using `gridExtra` the problem is that the plots don't align:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p2, p1, ncol=2)
```

[image]

And using `cowplot` the legends are somewhat centred:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(p1, p2, p2, p1, ncol=2, align="hv")
```

I tried adding `legend.justification` and/or `legend.position` but with no effect.

[image]

How can I get both the plots/legends aligned?

Comment: We could add `guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 3))` so that legends take up same width size.

Comment: @zx8754 my real data has many more factor levels, ranging from 2-10 based on facet. There's no way around having several columns but varying numbers of columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [the experimental `egg` package](https://github.com/baptiste/egg).

```
grid.draw(ggarrange(plots=list(p1,p2,p2,p1)))
```

Note that ggplot2 has a habit of breaking this type of code with every update, so consider it a fragile workaround.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what do I have to do to get access to function `ggarrange` though?

Comment: @beetroot : `devtools::install_github('baptiste/egg')` to install it

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works with my example now for me, too. But with my actual data I get the error: `Error: ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE`

Comment: @beetroot can you share a minimal example?

Comment: Sure, seems like the problem is an uneven number of plots? `grid.draw(ggarrange(plots=list(p1,p2,p2,p1,p2)))`

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help and also for your great work on gridExtra etc. :)